# Cart total returns multiple numbers node js express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Cart total is returning multiple numbers

[My cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRMQ2.png)

It seems to me that the problem is when multiplying the quantity by the value of the product

Cart.js Route

```
router.post("/cart", Auth, async (req, res) => {
const owner = req.user._id;
const { itemId, quantity } = req.body;

try {
const cart = await Cart.findOne({ owner });
const item = await Item.findOne({ _id: itemId });

if (!item) {
  res.status(404).send({ message: "item not found" });
  return;
}
const price = item.price;
const name = item.name;
//If cart already exists for user,
if (cart) {
  const itemIndex = cart.items.findIndex((item) => item.itemId == itemId);
  //check if product exists or not

  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    let product = cart.items[itemIndex];
    product.quantity += quantity;

    cart.bill = cart.items.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
      let cur = curr.cost.match(/\d./g).join('')
        return acc + Number(cur); 
      }, 0)
    
    cart.items[itemIndex] = product;
    await cart.save();
    res.status(200).send(cart);
  } else {
    cart.items.push({ itemId, name, quantity, price });

    await cart.save();
    res.status(200).send(cart);
  }
} else {
  //no cart exists, create one
  const newCart = await Cart.create({
    owner,
    items: [{ itemId, name, quantity, price }],
    bill: parseInt(quantity * price),
  });
  return res.status(201).send(newCart);
}}});
```

Model Cart

[Cart.js Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioTRn.png)

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: what do you mean multiple numbers? What is the fix that you want? You want to limit how many decimals you show?

Comment: What I meant is that the sum is showing too many decimals, for example: 109.99 * 2 + 109.99 * 3 + 109.99 * 1 was supposed to be 659.93 but in reality it is showing 659.9399999999999

Comment: That is because of how numbers are implemented in javascript. https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Because of how [javascript handles floating point numbers](https://floating-point-gui.de), weird things like this can happen (instead of `109.99 * 3` to equal `329.97`, it equals `329.96999999999997`).

One solution for this, if you know how many decimals you want, is to call [Number.prototype.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method (for example `cart.bill = cart.bill.toFixed(2)`